# Image View and Label added on UIButton prevent me from tapping - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uibutton, uiimageview

I added a ImageView and a Label on a custom UIButton, the problem is that they prevent me from tapping the button:

```
class CustomSignInButton : UIButton{


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
   
    styleButton()
    
}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



fileprivate func styleButton(){
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mail").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    
    let signInLabel = UILabel(text: "Sign In with Email", font: UIFont(name: "avenir-black", size: 13), textColor: .white, textAlignment: .left, numberOfLines: 1)
    
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, signInLabel])
    stackView.distribution = .fill
   
    
    stackView.centerYToSuperview()
    stackView.centerXToSuperview()
    stackView.spacing = 20
    self.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 8, left: 12, bottom: 8, right: 20))
    
    
    
}
}
```

I actually need them set in this way but I obviously would like to know how to implement the tapping ability over those two objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable user interaction on `imageview`, `label` and on 'stackView'

```
fileprivate func styleButton(){
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mail").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        
        let signInLabel = UILabel(text: "Sign In with Email", font: UIFont(name: "avenir-black", size: 13), textColor: .white, textAlignment: .left, numberOfLines: 1)
        signInLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, signInLabel])
        stackView.distribution = .fill
       
        
        stackView.centerYToSuperview()
        stackView.centerXToSuperview()
        stackView.spacing = 20
        self.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 8, left: 12, bottom: 8, right: 20))
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I needed to set stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false too